Copy all log entries in one google cloud log to another log
I have a google cloud project with two logs named project/myproject/logs/A and project/myproject/logs/B. I am no longer sending any log entries to the first log. I would like to copy all the logs out of A into B and then delete A.
Log A contains about 1M log entries. I was thinking of just reading them all one-by-one and writing them back again to B using a Go program. This is a batch process that only needs to be run once, so it doesn't need to process new live logs. The problem I ran into is a rate limit exceeded error, which I suppose makes sense since I'm fetching a lot of pages of log entries.
What would be the recommended way to batch-process historical log entries? By this I mean I want to run a Go function on every entry in project/myproject/logs/A, or perhaps in some other way write them all to project/myproject/logs/B without modifying anything other than the log name.
I looked into google cloud log sinks, but I think this would only work for new incoming log entries. What I need is to batch-process all the historical log entries. Maybe I can run a mapreduce or something over the historical log entries?
FWIW the exact error I see is
googleapi: Error 429: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Read requests' and limit 'Read requests per minute' of service 'logging.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:xxxxxxxxx'.


Well, in case anyone else comes looking, I ended up solving this by sleeping for a couple of seconds after each page. Works pretty well for logs with up to a few million entries but would take a long time beyond that.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "github.com/alexflint/go-arg"
    "google.golang.org/api/logging/v2"
)

func Main() error {
    ctx := context.Background()
    var args struct {
        From    string `arg:"positional,required"`
        To      string `arg:"positional,required"`
        Project string
        Limit   int
    }
    arg.MustParse(&args)

    // create logging client
    client, err := logging.NewService(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("error creating logging service; %w", err)
    }

    from := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/logs/%s", args.Project, args.From)
    to := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/logs/%s", args.Project, args.To)

    // iterate through the log entries
    var n int
    err = client.Entries.List(&logging.ListLogEntriesRequest{
        ResourceNames: []string{"projects/" + args.Project},
        Filter:        fmt.Sprintf("logName = %q", from),
        PageSize:      50000,
    }).Pages(ctx, func(page *logging.ListLogEntriesResponse) error {
        var out []*logging.LogEntry
        for _, entry := range page.Entries {
            if entry.LogName != from {
                log.Printf("warning: got a log entry for log %q, ignoring", entry.LogName)
                continue
            }

            entry.LogName = to
            out = append(out, entry)

            n++
            if args.Limit > 0 && n >= args.Limit {
                break
            }
        }

        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

        _, err := client.Entries.Write(&logging.WriteLogEntriesRequest{
            Entries: out,
        }).Context(ctx).Do()
        if err != nil {
            return fmt.Errorf("error writing log entries: %w", err)
        }

        // response contains nothing of interest
        log.Printf("wrote %d log entries, ignored %d (%d total so far)", len(out), len(page.Entries)-len(out), n)

        if args.Limit > 0 && n >= args.Limit {
            log.Printf("reached limit of %v", args.Limit)
            return io.EOF
        }

        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)

        return nil
    })
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return fmt.Errorf("error listing log entries (after %d): %w", n, err)
    }

    log.Printf("finished copying %d log entries", n)

    return nil
}

func main() {
    log.SetOutput(os.Stdout)
    log.SetFlags(0)
    err := Main()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

